# Is there stationarity?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, lags, acf-pacf

[image]

I'm trying to analyze a financial time series, these are the ACF and PACF returns graph. What could I say? Lag–9 and lag–15 are significant? I would say they are not, and there is not weak stationarity.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you shouldn't use the ACF and PACF to test for stationarity.

It is better to use various types of unit root tests, such as the Dickey-Fuller test, the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test, the Phillips–Perron test or the Kwiatkowski–Phillips–Schmidt–Shin (KPSS) tests.

Comment: And what do ACF and PACF mean? I have not fully understand: if I look at this graph I can conclude?

Comment: @CoFo18 the ACF and PACF are used to determine the best number of lagged values to include in your time series model, i.e. should your model be $y_t = f(y_{t-1},y_{t-2})$ (2 lags) or $y_t = f(y_{t-1},y_{t-2},y_{t-3})$ (3 lags), etc... in an AR model, this corresponds to the order p of the model.

Comment: and in my model the p order of the AR should be 9 or 15? is it necessary to fit the AR(9) model? My time series seems to be similar to a white noise

Comment: I don't know what the purpose of your analysis is. If you are trying to forecast using ARMA/ARIMA models, the you need to test for stationarity. Depending on the outcome of that test, you would want to transform the data, then you do the ACF and PACF to determine the orders of the model.

Comment: My purpose is the following:
- Performance inspection
- Identification of the possible structure on average
- Identification of the structure in volatility
- Verification of the leverage effect
- Once the final model has been identified, graphic representation of the estimated volatility